# Add an Azure internal load balancer to existing RM Virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I am migrating a solution from Classic VM's, for which I have a Web App that is accessing via ACLs on an endpoint, to new Resource Manager VMs, running in a Virtual Network.  My goal is to use Point-to-Site so that my web app can access the VMs using internal IP and not via an Internet call.

I set up a new virtual network.  Inside of this, I created new RM VM's, and configured them with my service.  This is all running fine, and my service (Elasticsearch) is able to communicate between all clusters.

What I want to do now is add an internal load balancer to the VN.  I am finding this hard to do as all the information I can find creates a *new* network, and *new* VMs in the process of creating the load balancer.  Also, many of the commands (though I think these might be Classic mode commands) ask for a ServiceName.  I have not created a service.

I would really like to know the order in which these resources should be created.  To repeat, at the end, I would like to have a new Virtual Network, with an internal load balancer, to which I can create a Point-to-Site connection, so that my Web App can make a non-internet call, and have it round-robin distributed to one of the VMs in the cluster.

Comment: Do you really need a point to site setup. once you set up a Vnet and communication via private endpoints VMs/ cloud services communicate internally right ?

Answer (score 0):

When using the internal loadbalancer, you populate the backend pool by associating a NIC on the vnet to an LB backend. When you integrate a webapp on a vnet, you don't directly manage the NIC since this works through P2S VPN.

This means you can't currently add the internal IP address of a webapp to an ILB. If you want to loadbalance between webapps on a vnet by internal IP, I would suggest looking into [Azure Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/application-gateway/). With that, you can add FQDNs or internal IPs on the backend pool when you create the gateway instead of associating the NICs.

If you want to go forward with an internal loadbalancer, for example when loadbalancing VMs, you can also do that with an existing vnet.

You can follow the steps on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps/, which I'm guessing was the starting point for your question.

The article goes through the prereqs for creating a load balancer and then creates the loadbalancer itself. The first two snippets are for creating a subnet config and a vnet with that config:

```
$backendSubnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name LB-Subnet-BE -AddressPrefix 10.0.2.0/24

$vnet= New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name NRPVNet -ResourceGroupName NRP-RG -Location "West US" -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $backendSubnet
```

This is included, because the next step (creating the frontend ip config) requires a subnetID as input. If you already have a vnet with a subnet to use, you can replace the two lines above with

```
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name YourNetwork -ResourceGroupName YourRG
```

The rest of the steps would then be, assuming that you with the frontend IP to be on the first subnet of your vnet and the IP space used in the sample matches the one on your vnet:

```
$frontendIP = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name LB-Frontend -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.2.5 -SubnetId $vnet.subnets[0].Id

$beaddresspool= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "LB-backend"
$inboundNATRule1= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name "RDP1" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -Protocol TCP -FrontendPort 3441 -BackendPort 3389

$inboundNATRule2= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name "RDP2" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -Protocol TCP -FrontendPort 3442 -BackendPort 3389

$healthProbe = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerProbeConfig -Name "HealthProbe" -RequestPath "HealthProbe.aspx" -Protocol http -Port 80 -IntervalInSeconds 15 -ProbeCount 2

$lbrule = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "HTTP" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Probe $healthProbe -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 80
$NRPLB = New-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName "NRP-RG" -Name "NRP-LB" -Location "West US" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -InboundNatRule $inboundNATRule1,$inboundNatRule2 -LoadBalancingRule $lbrule -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Probe $healthProbe
```

Assuming the backend NICs are already created, use the following code for each NIC to add them to the loadbalancer backend pool:

```
$lb= Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer –name NRP-LB -resourcegroupname NRP-RG
$backend= Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -name backendpool1 -LoadBalancer $lb

$nic=Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface –name lb-nic1-be -resourcegroupname NRP-RG
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools=$backend
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

Comment: I currently have my VM nics in the Front End pool of my VN. I had assumed the intent was that the front end was the application layer, and the back end could be used for something like a database layer. In this case, I would only be using the front end.
My web app, to be clear, is not part of the VN. That is why I wanted to create the Point-to-Site.
I had assumed I could have a lb at the front of the VN, and direct requests to the VMs from there. This is what I thought was implied by the image on the article.  Do I need to have a single nic on the front, and then a lb to route to the back?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the front end pool of my VN'? Is that a subnet? The terms frontend and backend in load balancer context have nothing to do with application layout (backends/databases/etc), but rather with the fact that a loadbalancer receives requests on the frontend and routes those to the network interfaces associated with its backend pool. This loadbalancer setup can be anywhere on the vnet.